# What should we do of belongings of the person who is no more?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras

What should we do of belongings of the person who is no more? Like what should we do with cloths and other things of that person?

Comment: On the 11th day pooja the clothes are given to a mahabrahmin. If you don’t have a mahabrahmin then donate the clothes/ sell them off. Note: mahabrahmin is different from normal Brahmin. You can’t give it to any and every Brahmin. What is required is a mahabrahmin - ones who eat at the house of a jajaman during sutak.

Comment: @Archit Post an answer.

Comment: Yes please post an answer

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto and mr talk, no Scriptural reference :(

Comment: oouuch it hurts, but lets wait for that then

Comment: @Archit Look in Smritis.